# Multiple detached webview instances seen in chrome devices when opening and closing the cordova android app

Tags: android, cordova, webview, google-chrome-devtools

Every time I open and close up the cordova app again on my Android phone I see multiple detached webviews in chrome devices. What do these detached webviews mean? Is this like a leak or something? Is there a way to recover the detached webviews? The detached webviews can still be inspected though.

Comment: do not use phonegap /cordova. It's easy things for ppls who know js/css/html but apk's always laggy.

Comment: I am also seeing multiple detached webview instances in my inspect pane.  But when I investigate the activity situation using "adb shell dumpsys activity activities", I only see a single Activity.  So I am confused why chrome is showing so many.  Btw, I am not using phonegap/cordova.

Comment: I'm experiencing this same issue. It seems to only occur when pressing the "Open" button directly after installing the app. If "Done" is pressed instead, this issue doesn's occur. I know this doesn't explain why this is happening, but maybe it will help narrow the issue down.

Comment: I am using a list of Android WebViews and when I scroll up and down too fast, these detached views appear on chrome devices. Also these detached views seem to hold a significant amount of heap memory. I guess they are appearing because the webview is cast out of the screen before its DOM can be loaded, but that's just half minded reasoning. I still don't know why this occurs.