# Multiple detached webview instances seen in chrome devices while navigating in hybrid android app

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, android-webview, web-inspector

We have an hybrid android application. I am trying to navigate from a `WebView` to a `Native` context back and forth. Using `chrome://inspect/#devices` I get to notice that multiple instances of device inspected are `detached` while one of all would be `attached` as displayed in chrome. 
Referring to [SO-28254614](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28254614/multiple-detached-webview-instances-seen-in-chrome-devices-when-opening-and-clos), now I have not developed the WebView though, but to what I know about our application the WebView are not designed using Cordova and are in JS.
An the question that I have are :

- Why is it so that we see these detached devices on chrome?
- Could this be a possibility of a leak in Android WebView?

Comment: Are you experiencing a performance compromise while you are browsing in your app's WebView?

Here are the Google Docs regarding memory leaks: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/memory-problems/memory-diagnosis

Probably won't help, but this is an umbrella bug for eclipse regarding issues with detached web view.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=276221

Comment: @ElonZito  Performance of webviews are comparatively slower in respect to the native context. Would follow the performance checks and keep an eye on the Bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the way these web inspectors work is that they use the [RemoteDebug Protocol](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/protocol/1.1/index).

This protocol defines the various messages and commands that are exchanged to let you 'inspect' your pages.

One instance of the inspector can only connect to one client at a time. So assuming that you are switching to and fro web-views and native context, you are basically spawning new webviews for every new context switch.

This would indicate that the previously opened webviews are now 'orphaned' and for all practical purposes `detached`.

You can try to inform the VM that a webview is no longer in use by calling `destroy()` on the webview to let the garbage collector know it is no longer required.

Hope this provides a deeper understanding on what is happening behind the scenes.

Comment: My current app is also a hybrid, and this answer is right on the money.  The situation you describe is summed up perfectly by Sunny.  This is totally normal behaviour as far as I'm aware, and I would say the answer to your question _Could this be a possibility of a leak in Android WebView?_ is no.